# Drilling holes in 'styroglass'

Tags: drill, adhesive, glass, plastic

I have a sheet of styroglass, which I assume by the name to be a clear polystyrene.

I want to drill some M4 holes into it, which are about 2.5cm separated from each other.

However, I only have drillbits for wood and stone here. Will I be able to dill the holes with these or do I risk to crack the material? Should I go for another type of dillbit or just use strong glue?

Answer (score 1):

Clear polystyrene appears to be a type of plastic, so I would say a wood drill bit should work.  However, be careful about heat - you dont want to melt it.  Take a break to let the bit cool if its starts getting hot.

Answer (score 1):

Polystyrene is prone to both melting and shattering or cracking. Sharp wood bits with very light pressure at high speed have worked best for me. Step up in size for larger holes. It can be helpful to clamp the sheet between layers of plywood, as well.